# программа которая получает на вход строку текста и экранирует в ней все одинарные и двойные кавычки

Tags: python, input

```
Sample Input:
I'm studying "Python"

Sample Output:
I\'m studying \"Python\"
```

Comment: replace('"','\\"') и тд

Answer (score 0):

```
Sample = input()
print(Sample.replace('"', '\\"'))
```

[Python 3 – Строковая функция replace()](https://andreyex.ru/yazyk-programmirovaniya-python/uchebnik-po-python-3/python-3-strokovaya-funkciya-replace/)
[Функция replace() в Python](https://artemsannikov.ru/language/python/str-python/replace-str-python/#:%7E:text=%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20replace()%20%D0%B2%20Python%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5.&text=%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20str%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC,%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD.)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: а одинарные кавычки?

Comment: я вам дал почти готовый пример, попробуйте разобраться сами, добавил ссылки на для помощи